# CSS Menu Toggle isn't correct color when viewed in smaller screenHi

Tags: html, css, colors, menu, responsive

I have been trying to make this responsive CSS/HTML menu work, and it's displayed in the colors I want when it's in full screen/normal desktop view, but when I view it in "responsive" view e.g a phone resolution, the menu colors aren't displaying the right way...

As per the full screen version the colors should be as follows

menu text - #278189
background - #fff
hover background - #3A3A3A

I have trawled through the code time after time but cannot see why this isn't working? for some other strange reason "home" "about" and "contact" have a black hover background.

Another minor issue (not massively bothered but would be nice to know) is when in full screen there is a "home" button which will link to the index page, but in the smaller version there is a "menu" button too...?

TIA

Dan

```
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Primeheat | Chichester Plumbing &amp; Heating Installation, 
Maintenance &amp; Emergency Breakdown</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

        <nav>
    <div id="logo">Your Logo here</div>

    <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Plumbing</label>
                <a href="#">Plumbing</a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Installation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Breakdown</a></li>
                </ul> 

            </li>
            <li>

            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Heating</label>
            <a href="#">Heating</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Installation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                <li>


            </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


<div id="navbar2" div id class="navbar2">   

    <h1 class="h1">Welcome to Primeheat Plumbing & Heating</h1>

</div>

</body>

</html>


body {
background: #212121;
font-size:22px;
line-height: 32px;
color: #278189;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
word-wrap:break-word !important;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
font-size: 60px;
text-align: center;
color: #278189;
}   

h3 {
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 34px;
text-align: center;
color: ##278189;;
}

h3 a {
color: ##278189;;
}

a {
color: ##278189;;
}

h1 {
margin-top: 100px;
text-align:center;
font-size:60px;
line-height: 70px;
font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
}

#container {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 890px;
}

p {
text-align: center;
}

.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
display: none;
}

 /* Giving a background-color to the nav container. */
 nav { 
margin:0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#logo {
display: block;
padding: 0 30px;
float: left;
font-size:20px;
line-height: 60px;
}

/* Since we'll have the "ul li" "float:left"
 * we need to add a clear after the container. */

nav:after {
content:"";
display:table;
clear:both;
}

/* Removing padding, margin and "list-style" from the "ul",
 * and adding "position:reltive" */
nav ul {
float: right;
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
}

/* Positioning the navigation items inline */
nav ul li {
margin: 0px;
display:inline-block;
float: left;
background-color: #fff;
}

/* Styling the links */
nav a {
display:block;
padding:14px 20px;  
color:#278189;
font-size:17px;
text-decoration:none;
}


nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #3A3A3A; }

/* Background color change on Hover */
nav a:hover { 
background-color: #3A3A3A; 
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default
* and giving it a position of absolute */
nav ul ul {
display: none;
position: absolute; 
/* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
top: 60px; 
}

 /* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
display:inherit;
}

/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
width:170px;
float:none;
display:list-item;
position: relative;
}

/* Second, Third and more Tiers 
 * We move the 2nd and 3rd etc tier dropdowns to the left
 * by the amount of the width of the first tier.
*/
nav ul ul ul li {
position: relative;
top:-60px;
/* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */ 
left:170px; 
}


/* Change ' +' in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }


/* Media Queries
-------------------------------------------- */

@media all and (max-width : 768px) {

#logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
}

nav {
    margin: 0;
}

/* Hide the navigation menu by default */
/* Also hide the  */
.toggle + a,
.menu {
    display: none;
}

/* Stylinf the toggle lable */
.toggle {
    display: block;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding:14px 20px;  
    color:##278189;
    font-size:17px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:none;
}

.toggle:hover {
    background-color: #278189;
}

/* Display Dropdown when clicked on Parent Lable */
[id^=drop]:checked + ul {
    display: block;
}

/* Change menu item's width to 100% */
nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    }

nav ul ul .toggle,
nav ul ul a {
    padding: 0 40px;
}

nav ul ul ul a {
    padding: 0 80px;
}

nav a:hover,
nav ul ul ul a {
    background-color: #000000;
}

nav ul li ul li .toggle,
nav ul ul a,
nav ul ul ul a{
    padding:14px 20px;  
    color:#464646;
    font-size:17px; 
 }


nav ul li ul li .toggle,
nav ul ul a {
    background-color: #3a3a3a; 
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
nav ul ul {
    float: none;
    position:static;
    color: #278189;
    /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
}

/* Hide menus on hover */
nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: none;
}

/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul ul ul li {
    position: static;
    /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */ 

}

}

@media all and (max-width : 330px) {

nav ul li {
    display:block;
    width: 94%;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before going into your stated problem, I would like to point out some obvious mistakes in your code. First mistake, you typed some of the color hex codes wrongly. You type extra hashtags and semicolons. Not only this h3 tag, but others as well. Check your code properly.

```
h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  color: ##278189;; /* should be #278189; */
}
```

Second mistake, why do you style the same tag (h1) twice? I can understand you style it twice if one of them is either inside a media query or nested under other tags or classes/ids, but it's not.

```
h1 {
 font-size: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #278189;
}   

h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:60px;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
}
```

Ok, to solve your problem:

You mentioned that menu colors aren't displaying correctly in mobile resolution.

Under the media query `@media all and (max-width : 768px)`, you have something like this below. Just change it to the color that you want, which is #3A3A3A.

```
.toggle:hover {
  background-color: #278189; /* it's using the menu text color. change this to the color you want, which is #3A3A3A */
}
```

If you want the nav items to have the same hover background color, change this as well, also under the same media query.

```
nav a:hover,
  nav ul ul ul a {
  background-color: #000000; /* #000000 is black color. Change this */
}
```

If the submenu text is meant to have the #278189 too, change this.

```
nav ul li ul li .toggle,
nav ul ul a,
nav ul ul ul a{
  padding:14px 20px;  
  color: #464646; /* change this too... */
  font-size:17px; 
}
```

> Another minor issue (not massively bothered but would be nice to know) is when in full screen there is a "home" button which will link to the index page, but in the smaller version there is a "menu" button too...?

The "menu" button that you mention is for collapsing the dropdown menu on mobile resolution. You click it, the dropdown menu will be shown. It's from this line of html code:

```
<label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
```

If you were to remove this whole line, you can't get the dropdown menu on mobile resolution anymore, as the dropdown css code are all handled by the `toggle` class.

Basically, your mentioned problems aren't big. If you're not sure where does the color come from, why is it showing the wrong color, etc, you can always use inspect element from your browser to look for it ([read here for more info if you don't know much about inspect element](https://zapier.com/blog/inspect-element-tutorial/). Also, always make sure your code is free from syntax errors ([read more about css syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Syntax)), like the color hex codes like I mention above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, it answered all my questions and solved all the problems above. I haven't done this in a long time so very rusty but eye to detail is obviously key. I will read up on inspect element and can I clear up syntax errors by using the HTML/CSS cleanup function in Dreamweaver? Thanks for your help, again!

Comment: You can also use something like [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/). All the best.